# Core Data Operation In Multiple Thread ,Memory Leak?

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, memory-leaks, nsmanagedobjectcontext

**RESOLVED**

I am working on a `core data` application with multi thread operation , in which I need to deal with many documents.

I am performing  insert , delete , update  etc in core data using these document details.

Since dealing with huge number of datas, I am using separate `NSManagedObjectContext` for each thread operation.(keeping a main context for mainThread).

For convenient `NSManagedObjectContext` management I  set the context into thread dictionary.

I dont have any critical memory loose by using this method, but when i run the xcode instrument leaks tool, it showing number of leaked object related to `NSManagedObjectContext`.

But I found that the context is removing completely when thread exit.(since current thread kill itself after its operation , thread dictionary also cleaned).

Below giving the code for getting managedObjectContext

```
-(NSManagedObjectContext*)managedObjectContext     {

    NSManagedObjectContext *context = nil;
    if ([NSThread isMainThread])    {
        if (!managedObjectContext) {
            context = [NSManagedObjectContext newContextForPersistentStoreCoordinator:[self persistentStoreCoordinator]];
                [self setManagedObjectContext:context];
        }

        context = managedObjectContext;
    } 
    else    {
        //find context for this thread.
        NSMutableDictionary *threadDictionary = [[NSThread currentThread] threadDictionary];
        context = [threadDictionary objectForKey:kManagedObjectContextKey];
        if (!context)   {
            //create a new context for this thread.
            context = [NSManagedObjectContext newContextForPersistentStoreCoordinator:[self persistentStoreCoordinator]];
            [threadDictionary setObject:context forKey:kManagedObjectContextKey];
            [context setUndoManager:nil];

            //to start observing context through DidSaveNotification.
            [self startObserveContext:context];
        }
   }

    return context;
}
```

And the instrument showing no leaks  shows when I used only single/main NSManagedObjectContext.But it cause memory problem while dealing large documents , so i need separate NSManagedObjectContext for each thread operation

Can any one tell me, what will be a good solution for this problem?...
Any other method for handling core data context in multiple thread would be appreciated ..

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the following modifications in my code

```
-(NSManagedObjectContext*)managedObjectContext     {

    NSManagedObjectContext *context = nil;
    if ([NSThread isMainThread])    {
        if (!managedObjectContext) {
            context = [NSManagedObjectContext newContextForPersistentStoreCoordinator:[self persistentStoreCoordinator]];
                [self setManagedObjectContext:context];
        }

        context = managedObjectContext;
    } 
    else    {
        //find context for this thread.
        NSMutableDictionary *threadDictionary = [[NSThread currentThread] threadDictionary];
        context = [threadDictionary objectForKey:kManagedObjectContextKey];
        if (!context)   {
            //create a new context for this thread.
            context = [NSManagedObjectContext newContextForPersistentStoreCoordinator:[self persistentStoreCoordinator]];
           [context setUndoManager:nil];

            //to start observing context through DidSaveNotification.
            [self startObserveContext:context];
            [threadDictionary setObject:context forKey:kManagedObjectContextKey];
            [context release]
            context = nil;

return [threadDictionary objectForKey:kManagedObjectContextKey];
        }
   }

    return context;
}
```

Previoulsy the [NSManagedObjectContext newContextForPersistentStoreCoordinator:[self persistentStoreCoordinator]]; method return autoreleased NSManagedObjectContext, i removed the autorelease,

and in the operation start{} method , i added ..

My NSOperation Class

```
start {
.........
........
.......
 NSManagedObjectContext *currentContext = (NSManagedObjectContext *)[[[NSThread currentThread] threadDictionary] objectForKey:kManagedObjectContextKey];
    [currentContext reset];
    [[[NSThread currentThread] threadDictionary] removeObjectForKey:kManagedObjectContextKey];
    currentContext = nil;

}
```

after all functions in start (end of start added context removing lines).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of threads and thread dictionaries, why not use blocks? There's a nice explanation here : http://www.cimgf.com/2011/05/04/core-data-and-threads-without-the-headache/

(I was about to post the methods I use, but that tutorial is much better)

Comment: Thank you very much for you idea @Marcelo, but the problem is i m already finished almost all modules in my project, I think this seems to difficult if i change al these to blocks ..?...or can you post the method you used ?

Comment: I checked the link you given , they referring an open source project in git hub MagicalRecord(http://github.com/magicalpanda/magicalrecord), the same thing(setting context in thread dictionary )we can see there also